# dyld: F_ADDFILESIGS failed for .... with errno=1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, dylib

I have created a C++ dynamic library using Xcode. When I try to load this dynamic library in my app, I am getting the following error:

> dyld: F_ADDFILESIGS failed for TestApp.app/DylibTest.dylib with
>   errno=1

What do i need to do in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: This problem is resolved after i resign the dynamic library.

Comment: i have same problem too, may you write any details?

Comment: Issue wen away after i resigned the library using code sign tool